# Where is the Environment (Development, Production, etc) set in Azure?

Tags: .net, azure, .net-core

We have two subscriptions setup in Azure, one intended for Dev and Testing and another for the live Production hosting. I have an app service deployed to each that I created a simple API method to return the current environment from the IWebHostEnvironment, just returns:

```
env.EnvironmentName
```

But in each case the value returned is 'Production'.

Where in Azure do I set the DEV subscription to be env = Development?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to set it as an environment variable by going to:
Configuration -> Application Settings.
Set the Name to `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` and value to anything you like such as `DEVELOPMENT`.

Comment: Hey thanks @Edward, that did indeed do the trick! I've always been on AWS so I am not very familiar with Azure and where things go. Plus I was looking too hard under the subscription settings and not enough under the App Service itself. Thanks again.